# How to assign multiple civilizations to the same player?

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-hd

Is there anyway to play controlling multiple civilizations?
For example: 4 civilizations controlled by the same player (me) as it would be a "solitaire".

Thanks.

Comment: Furthest I've got is to use the map editor to make a single civ able to use the units of the others, I do not think what you want is possible since there are faction wide bonuses that applies to all units in that faction. Will controlling multiple civ means those bonus applies to all units? or will each sub-civ of the player receive their own respective bonuses while sharing team bonuses? Either way that is not supported in the original game, try looking at mods